# Parse JSON Dictionary with Python3

Tags: python-3.x

I have a JSON representation that looks like the following:

```
{
    "results": [
       {
         "vulnerabilities": [
         ],
       }
     ]
}
```

I tried to output just the vulnerabilities portion, but the following doesnt work:

```
for key, value in json_object.items():
    print(key, ' : ', value)
```

This prints out the whole `results` but not just the `vulnerabilities`

Comment: Indeed it's doing that.
https://i.imgur.com/xgMLdqM.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming multiple dicts in results, each with a `vulnerabilities` key, you can do:

```
json_object = {
    "results": [
       {
         "vulnerabilities": [
         ],
       }
     ]
}

for result in json_object['results']:
    for vuln in result['vulnerabilities']:
        print(vuln)
```

Comment: Your code splits out this https://i.imgur.com/x45GwtP.png

Comment: anyway to loop over each result within vulnerabilities?

Comment: HAve updated answer to iterate over `vulnerabilities` too.